# Binary searching NSArray without having the object to search but a condition

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray, binary-search

So, I have this array of objects with `NSNumber`s in it. I have a number of my own and I need to find a number in the array that's greater than my number by least margin.

How do I employ binary search for this?

The method : `indexOfObject:inSortedRange:options:usingComparator` accepts the object as a parameter and I don't have it. How do I do the binary search with this condition but without an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to supply an object - any object specifying the value of the item being searched. As long as the comparator knows how to extract the value, the `indexOfObject:inSortedRange:options:usingComparator:` would return a proper value.

You need to specify `NSBinarySearchingInsertionIndex` option to make the search return the position of the first item that's greater than your target value by the smallest amount, i.e. the insertion index for your new value.

```
NSNumber *target = ... // Your target number
int index = [sortedArray indexOfObject:target
    inSortedRange:NSMakeRange(0, sortedArray.count) 
    options:NSBinarySearchingInsertionIndex
    usingComparator:^(id lhs, id rhs) {
        return [lhs compare:rhs]
    }];
```

Comment: Why not simply `return [lhs compare:rhs]` in the comparator block? And you probably meant `indexOfObject:target`.

Comment: @MartinR You are right on both counts, thanks for the corrections!