# Binary Searching an NSArray of objects with matching key

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, binary-search

This question is tantalizing close to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21723915/binary-searching-nsarray-without-having-the-object-to-search-but-a-condition).

Say I have `NSArray` of `Foo` objects sorted on a particular property (e.g., say the objects have an `NSDate*` property named `date`):

```
@interface Foo : NSObject 
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate *date; // sort key
...
@end

...
NSArray *arrayOfFoos;
```

How do I perform a *binary search* of this array looking for an object with a particular date using `NSArray`'s provided method below? Here is my current attempt:

```
const NSInteger index = 
   [arrayOfFoos indexOfObject:date
                inSortedRange:(NSRange){0, arrayOfFoos.count}
                      options:NSBinarySearchingFirstEqual
              usingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
                                  NSDate *d = (NSDate*) obj1;
                                  Foo *foo = (Foo*)obj2;
                                  return [d compare:foo.date];
                               }];
```

Here I (incorrectly) assumed that the first parameter `obj1` would be the search key, and `obj2` would be the array element.

Note: I am trying to avoid wrapping the `date` key in a temporary `Foo` object (if that is possible).

Comment: In `arrayOfFoos`, I guess there are only `Foo` objects. So in the comparator block, `obj1` and `obj2` are both `Foo` objects. `NSDate *d = (NSDate*) obj1;`  doesn't seem correct.

Comment: Do to `obj1`, what you already do with `obj2`.

Comment: @Larme When searching an array (unlike sorting), only one of the objects in the comparison should be from the array (i.e., you are not comparing two elements from the array).

Comment: @trojanfoe As I noted, I am trying to avoid wrapping the search key in a temporary `Foo` object. If I do that, then I can do what you suggest.

Comment: @wcochran The docs say the comparator block is "A comparator block used to compare the object obj with elements in the array". I would have made the same assumption as you - so what in fact are the two objects passed into the block? Are they just the other way round?

Comment: @johnpatrickmorgan I bet you are correct -- if I switch `obj1` and `obj2` around I imagine it works -- I'll try it later when the code is in front of me. Of course I hate to depend on an undocumented feature.